# Global Variable is not used inside the function

Tags: python

Why when Variable total=100 is not used and counted in the function, it considered as 0

```py
total=100 #this is global variable

def sum(num1,num2):
    #Add both parameters and return them
    global total
    total = num1+num2 #here total is local variable
    print('inside the function local total:',total)

#now you can call sum function
sum(10,20)
print('outside the function:',total)
```

Comment: You are over writing your global. Why did you expect something different? Did you mean: `total += num1+num2`?

Comment: What is your output then?

Comment: [test code online Compiler -https://ideone.com/jDwBk1](https://ideone.com/jDwBk1) - This is the code that runs. but, I am not sure what it considered as 0. Can you share the output that you are getting

Comment: why don't you `return` something from the `sum` function

Comment: use return result instead. Using global variable is coding bad practice when you will have many lines of code this will be impossible to debug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you quite understand the concept of `global`. By writing `global total` in your function, you are telling it that for all subsequent references to the variable `total` *within* the function, it shall refer to the variable declared *outside* the function. Hence when you did `total = num1 + num2` inside the function, it modified the value of the `total` variable declared outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have both a global variable named total and a local variable also named total within the sum function. When you declare global total inside the function, you are indicating that you want to use the global variable total rather than creating a new local variable with the same name.

Here's a breakdown of what happens in your code:

You initialize a global variable total with a value of 100.

You define a function sum that takes two arguments, num1 and num2.

Inside the sum function, you declare global total, which means that you want to use the global total variable within this function.

You calculate the sum of num1 and num2 and assign it to the global total variable.

You print the value of the local total variable inside the function, which will show the sum of num1 and num2.

You call the sum function with the arguments 10 and 20, which modifies the global total variable to be 30.

Finally, you print the value of the global total variable outside the function, which will also be 30 because the function modified the global variable when it was called.

In summary, when you declare global total inside the sum function, it refers to the global total variable, and any changes made to it inside the function will affect the global variable. That's why, when you print total outside the function after calling it, it reflects the value modified within the function, which is 30 in this case.

Comment: There is no local variable total as the assignment is preceded by the global declaration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).